# How do I get the following equation using limits?

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let

\begin{align*}
u_{i}^{j+1} &:= u(x,t+\Delta t) \\
u_{i}^{j-1} &:= u(x,t-\Delta t) \\
u_{i}^{j}  &:= u(x,t) \\
u_{i-1}^{j} &:= u(x-\Delta x,t) \\
u_{i+1}^{j} &:= u(x+\Delta x,t)
\end{align*}

Then from

$$u_{i}^{j+1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}+u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr) -\dfrac{c\Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)$$

we get

$$\dfrac{1}{2}u_{i}^{j+1}+\dfrac{1}{2}u_{i}^{j+1}-\dfrac{1}{2}u_{i}^{j-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}u_{i}^{j-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}+u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)+u_{i}^{j}-u_{i}^{j}=\dfrac{c\Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggr(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggl)$$

if and only if

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)=\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-2u_{i}^{j} +u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)-\dfrac{c \Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)-\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j}+u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)$$

In the continuous limit, one should get

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\Delta x^{2}}{2 \Delta t}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-c\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\Delta t^{2}}{2}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

I'm not really sure how we get $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\Delta x^{2}}{2 \Delta t}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-c\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\Delta t^{2}}{2}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

from

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)=\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-2u_{i}^{j} +u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)-\dfrac{c \Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)-\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j}+u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)$$ using a continuous limit.

Comment: What book are you reading? Where is this from? Could you please cite the reference? This seems to be finite difference, which should be very standard materials.

Comment: It's from these notes https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/advection.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) used in numerical PDE. See in particular [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Relation_with_derivatives) part.

For instance
$$
\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\dfrac{1}{2\Delta t}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)
=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\dfrac{u(x,t+\Delta t)-u(x,t-\Delta t)}{2\Delta t}
=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t).
$$

---

For
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)
=\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-2u_{i}^{j} +u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)
-\dfrac{c \Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)
-\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j}+u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)$$
note that
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)\approx \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)\Delta t\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-2u_{i}^{j} +u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)
\approx \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2}\\
\dfrac{c \Delta t}{2 \Delta x}\biggl(u_{i+1}^{j}-u_{i-1}^{j}\biggr)
\approx {c \Delta t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\biggl(u_{i}^{j+1}-2u_{i}^{j}+u_{i}^{j-1}\biggr)
\approx \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\frac{(\Delta t)^2}{2}
$$
Now you sum the right hand side above together and divide by $\Delta t$ to get:
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\Delta x^{2}}{2 \Delta t}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-c\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\Delta t}{2}\dfrac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}
$$

Comment: when I try to take the limit, I get $\Delta t$ in the denominator, am I just supposed to multiply both sides of the equation by $\Delta t$?

Comment: @K.M: Sorry. Typo fixed.

Comment: Does it matter if the left side of the equation you've provided is different from what's given in the notes?

Comment: They are equivalent. Check for instance (2.4) of your notes.

Comment: thanks, I think that I was also getting confused from a possible typo in the notes

Comment: @K.M: See my edits. Indeed your notes should have a typo in the last term.